# Trying to assign supervisors to employees in Microsoft Access, lookup is giving me numbers instead of names?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm somewhat new to VBA and Access, and yet I need to make an access database for work.  I made the basic tables I need to track what we need, but I'm stuck trying to assign the supervisors to the employees.  I have four tables, two of which are:

Employees, which includes basic information like their name and position
Supervisors, which includes their name (linked to the above "name" field), and date promoted

I want to be able to go back to the Employees table and add who is their supervisor in a lookup field, but when I make a lookup off of the "names" from the Supervisors table I only get a number.  When I make a lookup off the "names" in the Employees table itself, it gives me everyone to choose from.  I want to limit the choices in this field to only supervisors so that a) other users don't mess it up and b) it's easier to use.

If you give me code in VBA or C++, I can understand it to a beginner-to-intermediate level, and can make a macro button if needed.  However, I'm thinking this is probably a problem of relationships or labels in my database.  Please help if you can.  Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like it's just showing the Primary Key rather than the name field.  Did you create it using a lookup wizard?  Make sure the 'Hide key column' is ticked.  For an existing field go into the table design and change the Column Widths property so the first column is 0.

Comment: To limit to Supervisors on the same section as the `Column Widths` is the `Row Source` just add `WHERE Position='Supervisor'` to the end.

Comment: I thought about the PK as well, but there is another column for that.  The names (which are pulled from the Employees table) are displaying ok on the supervisors table, but I have a feeling that it's because the column is formatted as a number.  I tried changing it to "text" but that somehow removes the lookup function.

Comment: Could you edit your question with some pictures please?  I'm not understanding how your tables are joining together - I can't see the need for a Supervisor table seeing as they're also employees which would duplicate data?  The edit button is just below the tags in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If [Name] in Supervisors table actually stores a number then combobox RowSource needs to be a query that joins tables so can retrieve actual name.

Instead of a separate Supervisors table, have a yes/no field in Employees that flags record as "Supervisor" and restrict combobox list to those records.

Advise not to build lookups in table. http://access.mvps.org/Access/lookupfields.htm

Name is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as names.

Comment: Haven't looked at that page for years. :)  Another favourite from the Ten Commandments on there is "Thou shalt never allow thy users to see or edit tables directly, but only through forms and thou shalt abhor the use of "Lookup Fields" which art the creation of the Evil One."